# Writing grep expression with special characters?

Tags: bash, grep

I've been trying to write a Grep expression that will go through all text files in a directory and return only the files that contain all patterns I am looking for. An example input file would be the following:

```
A   29  LIJ uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers
A   30  RTX uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    <=B
A   31  BRN uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    <=B
A   32  SJY uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    <=B
A   33  MRT uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers
A   34  MUY uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers
A   35  OOP uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers
```

I want to be able to search through all the .txt files in my directory and return only the files that contain **all** of the following:

```
A   30  RTX uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    <=B
A   31  BRN uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    <=B
A   32  SJY uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    uniteresting_numbers    <=B
```

If any of those three are not present, I want the file skipped over. I will know what two digit number and three letter code I am looking for in each case. I want to enter those as variables for the user to input. The thing I am looking for is files where all of my two digit numbers and three letter codes of interest have a <=B at the very end.

```
Here is the code I have thus far:

echo What do you want to name your output file? 
read myoutput
for file in *.txt; do
    if  grep -q "RTX$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]" <"$file"; then 
        if grep -q "BRN$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]" <"$file"" <"$file"; then
            if grep -q "SJY$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]" <"$file"" <"$file"; then
                echo "$file" >>"$myoutput".txt

    else
        echo not found
    fi
    fi 
    fi
done
```

Note, I've not added the part where the user inputs the three letter code and two digit number. That shouldn't be terrible.In the input data there is a tab character separating each of the columns. As I have it right now I can search through all of the way to the final tab and <=B.

I tried this without any luck:

```
echo What do you want to name your output file? 
read myoutput
for file in *.txt; do
    if  grep -q "RTX$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')$(printf '<=B')" <"$file"; then 
        if grep -q "BRN$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')$(printf '<=B')" <"$file"" <"$file"; then
            if grep -q "SJY$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]$(printf '\t')*[0-9]*$(printf '\t')$(printf '<=B')*" <"$file"" <"$file"; then
                echo "$file" >>"$myoutput".txt

    else
        echo not found
    fi
    fi 
    fi
done
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. In some cases I will have more than three <=B lines I am looking for. Is there an easy way to modify this to look for n number of <=B lines? 
Thank you all so much!

EDIT:
I moved to awk as suggested

To do this with awk I entered the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo What do you want to name your output file? 
read myoutput
for file in *.txt; do
    if awk '/30/ && /RTX/ && /B/' "$file"; then
        echo it worked
    fi
done
```

The phrase "it worked" appears 6 times. There are 6 files in the mini-directory I am testing this script on. Only 3 of these files actually match the awk pattern. How do I get the code after "then" to only execute on files that contain the awk pattern? I tried the following based on the tutorial here: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements

```
#!/bin/bash
echo What do you want to name your output file? 
read myoutput
for file in *.txt; do
    $ awk '{
    if ($2 =="30" || $3 == "RTX" || $7 == "B")
        echo it worked
}' "$file"
done
```

I was unsuccessful. Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: `$(printf '\t')` is **really** inefficient compared to writing `$'\t'`. Every command substitution is `fork()`ing off a whole new copy of your shell, setting up a FIFO pair to read its output with, etc. See discussion of [ANSI C-like strings](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) on the bash-hackers' wiki.

Comment: Beyond that, I would strongly suggest switching out `grep` for `awk` here; as a full-fledged programming language, you can use conditionals to only match B if A has been seen elsewhere in the file (f/e), so you can call awk only once and have that single instance check all your conditions in a single pass.

Comment: You don't need the nested `if` commands: `if grep -q "xxx" && grep -q "yyy" && grep -q "zzz"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I swapped over to awk. The code is much shorter now. I appreciate the suggestion! Can you help with the one little bug I am encountering please? I was unaware of awk today. Thank you again!

Comment: A proper [mcve] would be including a command to generate your test cases, so everything needed to reproduce the error described is present in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may not be same as your approach, please try the following:

```
myoutput="myoutput.txt"
for f in *.txt; do
    awk -v output="$myoutput" -v numbers="30 31 32" -v strings="RTX BRN SJY" '
    BEGIN {
        split(numbers, num)
        split(strings, str)
        delete matched
    }
    {
        for (n in num) {
            if (match($0, "^A\t" num[n] "\t" str[n] "\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t<=B$")) {
                matched[n]++
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for (n in num) {
            if (!matched[n]) {
                exit
            }
        }
        print FILENAME >> output
    } ' "$f"
done
```

You can assign the shell variables `numbers` and `strings` to whatever the user wants with arbitrary length.